# Web Service method name is not valid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I get the following error "Web Service method name is not valid" when i try to call webmethod from javascript

> System.InvalidOperationException: SaveBOAT Web Service method name is not valid.
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

**HTML Code :**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkAddBoat" OnClientClick="javascript:AddMyBoat(); return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**JS Code :**

```
function AddMyBoat() {
            var b = document.getElementById('HdnControlId').value;

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/AllService.asmx/SaveBOAT",
                data: { Pid: b },
                contentType: "application/text",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(dd) {
                    alert('Success' + dd);
                },
                error: function(dd) {
                    alert('There is error' + dd.responseText);
                }
            });
}
```

**C# Code (Web method in AllService.asmx file)**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveBOAT(int Pid)
{
    // My Code is here
    //I can put anythng here
    SessionManager.MemberID = Pid;
    return "";
}
```

I tried all solutions found on Stack Overflow and ASP.NET site.but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was a silly mistake.

remove `Static` keyword from method declaration.

```
[WebMethod]
public string SaveBOAT(string Pid)
{        
     SessionManager.MemberID = Pid;
     return "";
}
```

Comment: in my case public keyword is missing

Comment: hi, i face this error not frequent but it is occuring. my web method has public keyword and does not have static keyword. but still i encounter this error. Any idea about what cause the same?

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had copied another asmx file, but not changed the class property to the name of the new class in the asmx file itself (Right click on asmx file -> View Markup)

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error was that the Web Service method was declared "private" instead of "public"

Comment: Do you know why it forces it to be public

Comment: @John How would you expect to call a web service method if it was not public?

Comment: I would want to mark it as internal then expose via my own interfaces to another project.

Comment: @John The webservice IS the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, I think datatype should be JSON

```
       jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",  // or GET
            url: "/AllService.asmx/SaveBOAT",
            data: { Pid: b },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
            success: function(dd) {
                alert('Success' + dd);
            },
            error: function(dd) {
                alert('There is error' + dd.responseText);
            }
        });
```

And in C# Code change Pid to string

```
    [WebMethod]
     public static string SaveBOAT(string Pid)
     {        
      SessionManager.MemberID = Pid;
      return "";
     }
```

Comment: I tried your code and got this error "Unknown web method SaveBOAT.<br>Parameter name: methodName"

Comment: Remove static from  "public static string SaveBOAT(string Pid)".

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the similar issue. The solution includes checking everything related to ensuring all name, parameters are passed correctly as many have responded. Make sure that the web method name that we are calling in UI page is spelled correctly, the data, data types are correct and etc. In my case, I misspelled the web method name in my ajax call. It works fine once I found and corrected the name correctly.
For Ex: In .asmx class file, this is the method name "IsLeaseMentorExistWithTheSameName" but when I called from UI this is how I called:

```
var varURL = <%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Main/BuildCriteria.asmx") %> + '/IsLeaseMentorExistWithSameName';
```

Notice that the word "The" is missing. That was a mistake and I corrected and so it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you sir. This solved our issue. We did not include all the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As Sundar Rajan states, check the parameters are also correct. My instance of this error was because I had failed to pass any parameters (as a body in a POST request) and the asmx web method was expecting a named parameter, because of this the binding logic failed to match up the request to the method name, even though the name itself is actually correct.

```cs
[WebMethod]
        public object MyWebMethod(object parameter)
```

If there is no `parameter` in the body of the request then you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did U add `ServiceReference` Class. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.servicereference.aspx) once. Based on your comment I can tell what to do

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my soap method had a `List<string>` parameter. Couldn't figure out a way to make it work with the array parameter; so just converted the parameter to a `&`-delimited string (e.g. `val1&val2&val3`) and converted the parameter to an array in the service method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, one of the WebService receiving parameters was called `aId`. When I called it from javascript, I was sending the correct Id value, but the name of the sent variable was incorrectly called `bId`. So I just had to rename the WebService call, keep the correct value like before, and just change the variable name.