# Neither getting any error nor html2canvas image is getting saved to server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to save a html2canvas image to server side code in asp.net webmethod.For this i am trying to send parameters through jquery ajax click method.Every thing is fine on client side code as i am not getting any type of error or warning but at the same time i am not getting image at server side too.I am trying to figure out issue from longtime but not getting the way or the reason why is it happening.Here is my client side code..

```
 $("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            html2canvas($("#placeholder").get(0), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {

                    var img = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
                        data: "img=" + img,
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Please guys help me.I am totally struck into the situation.
Need a life savior.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my server side code..

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(string img)
{

    string fileNameWitPath = "D:/Kabir/custom_name.png";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(img);//convert from base64
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my webservice code ..

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment  the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(string img)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + "Test.jpg";
    //string fileNameWitPath = "D:\\Kabir\\custom_name.png";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(img);//convert from base64
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this giving this error in firebug..

```
System.InvalidOperationException: MyMethod Web Service method name is not valid.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Why is this error coming?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question.  I don't know what your ajax call is doing or any of the variables.  Perhaps review the FAQ for the product you're using?  http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html

Comment: @onskee What information you want?Do you need to see my server side code?

Comment: If you are expecting a server-side image to be generated, the server-side code may be helpful.

Comment: @onskee i updated my post with server side code .Please see

Comment: @onskee Please help me to solve this issue sir ,i have tried everything from my end but not able to solve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get it to create an image by calling an ASPX webmethod.  Once I moved the code to an ASMX web service, it created the image.  Make sure you have permissions on the folder, and for Windows, the front-slashes (`/`) on your `fileNameWitPath` variable need to be back-slashes (`\`)

**ASMX**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
// <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
[System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod()]
    public void MyMethod(string img)
    {
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + "Test.jpg";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs)) {
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
    $("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        html2canvas($("#placeholder").get(0), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "WebService1.asmx/MyMethod",
                            data: "img=" + img,
                            success: function (msg) {
                                alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Answer updated.  I wrote in VB and converted via online converter.  This may not be 100%.

Comment: I am getting error in webservice too.Please see my updated post with my webservice code and error desc

Comment: Searching StackOverflow can be your friend.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878064/web-service-method-name-is-not-valid

Comment: Thank you sir .That error got over but i got new error as "System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at WebService1.MyMethod(String img) in c:\Users\vikas\Desktop\JQPlot\App_Code\WebService1.cs:line 29"